# Add table row after creating table body using scalatags

Tags: html, scala, html-table, scala.js, scalatags

Using scalatags, normally I create a table like this:

```
table(
  thead(
    tr(
      th("A"),
      th("B")
    )
  ),
  tbody(
   tr(
    td("HELLO"),
    td("WORLD")
   ),
   tr(
    td("FOO"),
    td("BAR")
   )
  )
)
```

Is it also possible to add  `tr` elements after the table has been declared? Something like this would be great:

```
val myTableBody = tbody(
   tr(
    td("HELLO"),
    td("WORLD")
   )
)

table(
  thead(
    tr(
      th("A"),
      th("B")
    )
  ),
  myTableBody
)

if(myCondition){
  myTableBody.addTr( // this is what I am searching for
   tr(
    td("FOO"),
    td("BAR")
   )
  )
}
```

*edit: 
For clarification, at the moment I am doing something like this:

```
table(
  thead(
    tr(
      th("A"),
      th("B")
    )
  ),
  tbody(
   tr(
    td("HELLO"),
    td("WORLD")
   ),
   if(myCondition){
    tr(
     td("FOO"),
     td("BAR")
    )
   } else {
    tr() // this is a bit ugly
   }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can certainly be done, but has nothing to do with Scalatags per se. This is pretty normal DOM manipulation, and you need a library or framework for working with that. It *can* be done [in raw DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), but it's more common to develop web applications using frameworks such as React, or at least libraries such as jQuery. There are *zillions* of such options (including [a somewhat rough Scalatags-based on I built myself](https://github.com/jducoeur/gadgets)); you should choose which one best suits your needs...

Comment: I want to add new rows to the table object before building the html and adding it to my site. So, as far as I understand, as long as the table is not part of the DOM I don't think I can use DOM manipulation to edit it, no? *edit: in addition to scalatags, I already use jQuery.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Honestly, what you are currently doing (as shown in your edit) is the way I'd do it -- I believe it's the way stuff like that is intended to work in Scalatags.  It *might* be possible to lens down into `myTableBody`, find the correct node and reconstruct it, but I don't think I've ever seen it done, and I suspect it's a lot harder.  (My Gadgets library kind of does this with a tool called GadgetRef, but I think it's way too much effort for your needs.)